# Appcelerator/Titanium : createLoginButton fires error on android platform

Tags: android, facebook, titanium, appcelerator

i'm adding the Facebook module to my app in order to use the login Facebook button using appcelerator/titanium and alloy framework.

here is my code:

```
var fb = require('facebook'); 
fb.addEventListener('login',function(e){
  if(e.success){
        alert("connected");
  }else{
        alert("failure"); 
  }
});
fb.addEventListener('logout',function(e){
    if(e.success) {
      alert("successfully logged out"); 
    }else{
      alert("failure"); 
    }
});
var mybtn = fb.createLoginButton({
  'top':'160',
  'height':'35',
  'width':'80%'
}); 
$.login_form.add(mybtn);
```

It seems that this part of this code causes the problem:

```
var mybtn = fb.createLoginButton({
  'top':'160',
  'height':'35',
  'width':'80%'
}); 
$.login_form.add(mybtn);
```

The error is the following :

```
exception on thread: main msg:java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.copark.mobile/org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity}: Unexpected CallbackManager, please use the provided Factory.; Titanium 5.5.1,2016/09/27 05:39,b18727f
```

I don't really understand that error, and neither how to fix it. 
If anyone of you has the answer... :)

Thanks in advance,

Quentin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code after require:

```
fb.initialize();
if(Ti.Platform.name == 'android'){
    $.login_form.fbProxy = fb.createActivityWorker({lifecycleContainer: $.login_form});
}
```

On the android platform, in tiapp.xml or AndroidManifest.xml you must declare the following inside the  node

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:label="YourAppName" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation" />
```

You must also reference the string containing your Facebook app ID, inside the  node as well:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>
```

The app id goes into the the file /platform/android/res/values/strings.xml (or your custom theme), where you should define

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <!-- ... -->
        <string name="app_id">1234567890123456</string>
        <!-- ... -->
    </resources>
</xml>
```

where the number is of course the app ID. The app ID is not set programmatically.

Comment: Well, it seems to work as my Facebook button is finally displayed on my screen.. Thanks a lot for this answer !

Comment: However, i got this error message now  : "[ERROR] :  KrollProxy: (main) [10,10036] lifecycleContainer must be a WindowProxy or TabGroupProxy (TiWindowProxy)"